# I want to refresh this div and its content

Tags: javascript

I have this jQuery to refresh the div, once it reloads it removes the content inside the div. Can someone help me to fix it so it can refresh without removing the content in div?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var message = $('#show');
    $('#show').html('');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show" align="center">Refresh me</div>
```

Comment: what you mean _refresh_?

Comment: You currently assign an unused variable and empty a div every 3 seconds. What do you really want to do?

Comment: I would rather say "what did you expect?" :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
//I don't know why the heck you want to do these.
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var message = $('#show').text(); // retrieve the text bet^ the div
   setInterval(function() {
    $('#show').html(message); //Add the text bet^ the div
 }, 3000);
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show" align="center">Refresh me</div>
```

Comment: what do your code snippet? and how it answer to question?

Comment: Sorry that is not a better answer

Comment: I have a DIV that i want to refresh every 3s this code help but once it refresh it change my html file to plan text
`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        var message = $('#show').text(); 
        $('#show').html(message);
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
       
<div id="show">Helll</div>`

Comment: @PeterValentine, so use `html()` instead `text()`

Comment: now you want html inside div. You must be chelsea supporter